# SQL lookup, find and compare

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables in sql.

table 1 has

```
….      | phone_number | Token | data_date
```

table 2 has

```
….     | Token | name | Data_date
```

what I want to do is to look up the phone number from 1 and this gives the token and then to take this and look in table 2 and give me the name on a given date.

I tried
Intersect....

now I tried

```
select table1, Phone_number, token, data_date 
from table1 
where CALL_ANI='0797111111' 
  and data_date = '1-sep-20'

union

SELECT  Token, name, Data_date 
FROM table2
```

But problem 1 is it doesn't filter the date and problem 2 I don't think it is looking up the item

Im sure I am going about this totally wrong but any real world example help is really appreciated

result I would like is
put phone number in out comes name for that date

Comment: What is LIST? Also what database do you use ?

Comment: Those things are called "tables" in a relational database, not "list". I think you are looking for a JOIN between the two tables, rather than a UNION

Comment: Please provide few rows of data and expected results

Comment: @Ian . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please refer this to learn SQL Joins : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a `JOIN`:

```
select t1.*, t2.name
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.token = t1.token
where t1.call_ani = '0797111111' and t1.data_date = date '2020-09-01'
```

Notes:

- I would assume that `data_date` is of a date-like datatype, so I used a literal date for filtering (`date '2020-09-01'`) - depending on your database, the syntax for literal dates might vary.
- `table1` makes more sense that `list1`

Comment: Perfect!!! it works great. I was looking at it all upside down and back to front. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you have tables and want `JOIN`:

```
select l1.*, l2.name
from List1 l1 join
     List2 l2
     on l1.token = l2.token
where CALL_ANI='0797111111' and
      data_date = '1-sep-20';
```

Your date format is highly unorthodox.  That comparison should probably be one of:

```
data_date = '2020-09-01'
data_date = date '2020-09-01'
```

That is, use standard date formats.